# Why is Lighthouse considering clip: rect(0 0 0 0) as not a valid solution for accessibility

Tags: css, accessibility, clip, lighthouse

I have a form on my page with inputs and labels using correctly filled `for` and `id` attributes. After applying best practices for accessibility Chrome Lighthouse fails the tests over the use of

`clip: rect(0 0 0 0)`

Removing this line works fine, but it goes against the best practice for solving the issue with visible items for screenreaders/browsers.

Anyone have any idea why this happens or how to solve it?

```html
<label for="name" class="visually-hidden">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="name">
```

And as for CSS

```css
.visually-hidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    outline: 0;
    appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Is there any good reason for hiding the label for your input field? Accessibility isn't just for screenreaders, but also for sighted people who should know which data to enter.

Comment: @MattDiMu I simplified it here to an input field but it's for a dropdown; for sighted people there is enough information to be able to work with it but for screenreaders we wish to use the label correctly for extra information. So for sighted people it would be information overkill.

Comment: Probably your best option is to use **aria-label**, and forget about the standard  label

Comment: @vals unfortunately aria-label has a max of 74% screenreader support, so it's not as reliable to use: https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/

Comment: I would say that the appropiate category would be "`input type=text` with `aria-label` attribute", and it's marked as "fails in 1% - 24%  ..." So 74% would be the minimum support, not the max.  It would fail in NVDA+IE and SaToGo+IE. But I agree that it is not fully reliable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code satisfies success criterion [4.1.2 Name, Role, Value](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/name-role-value.html) because the name can be programmatically determined, but fails the success criterion for [3.3.2 Labels or Instructions: Labels or instructions are provided when content requires user input](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/minimize-error-cues.html) where label has to be visible

Note that the technique [H44: Using label elements to associate text labels with form controls](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html), clearly states:

> Check that the label element is visible.

---

"visually hidden" hacks are not "best practice". This should be definitely banned.

People with screenreaders do not need *more* information than people with no screenreader : they need *better* information.

By hiding text from screen, you cause two damages:

- people using screenreader in support would be hearing things they can't view on screen, may loose the visual focus, and become lost,
- people not using screenreader will have no clue of what the field is for.

The latter is particularly damaging for people using a screen magnifier or special contrast settings where context has to be very informative.